# Remove "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" from final sites

Tags: feature-request

Apparently "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" is part of help center > asking of each site.
(At least I've checked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta))

It's relevant only for sites still in beta stage.
Is it possible to remove it for sites not already in private-beta?

I know very similar [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre) has been already asked, but it didn't received any answer, so I ask it again.