# Private Beta link on the help > asking page

Tags: support, help-center

I was perusing the [help pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/asking) of GIS to make sure that my next question is on-topic for their site and I noticed something that was rather odd for a graduated site, a link that says

> [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

it appears that this is on other Help Pages as well, Meta being one of them.

Is there a reason why this is kept linked? Note that this is not a duplicate of [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre) asking for it to be removed.

Comment: @Sonic, why would this be support instead of discussion?

Comment: @Aurora0001, I don't think that this is a duplicate of that one, although very similar, that one is asking that something specific be done about link, whereas mine is asking if it was left intentionally and is provoking a discussion about the link.

Comment: @Malachi: "Is this intentionally left over, or does it need to be removed?" reduces to "[behavior X] should probably be removed, but I want to hear any counter-arguments", which is isomorphic to a bug report about behavior X.

Comment: [tag:discussion] is when you want opinion from community members. [tag:support] is when your question has a specific answer you're looking for, possibly from the team.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog you’re right... this is clearly a [tag:bug] though

Comment: why is it a bug?

Comment: @Malachi because it makes absolutely no sense...

Comment: @Cai makes no sense to tag it a bug or makes no sense to have it on every page?  maybe the answer to my question is that it was a removal that was meant for a graduation script.  I bet it is part of the site template.

Comment: I mean it makes no sense for the link to be there. Maybe the answer is that it’s meant to be removed on graduation, that would make sense.