# Help Center still says that Triage is "Stack Overflow only"; however, it's enabled on Physics since September

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, help-center, triage

Triage was [previously announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363552/) to be open to any site which wanted it. Now it seems [Physics has an active Triage queue](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13879). However, the [Help Center article](/help/reviews-intro) listing all the review queues still claims that Triage is Stack Overflow specific:

> [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow only - 500 reputation. The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort questions into groups: good as is, needs community editing, or should be closed/flagged.

(Side note: the link there is to Stack Overflow's article on Triage, and attempting to manually change the URL to [be on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/review-triage) results in a 404)

Please update the Help Center to reflect that Stack Overflow is not the only community with a Triage queue.

Comment: It *might* be that this is still an 'experiment' and depending on the outcome(s), it will return to be a SO-only queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just changed this part to "Stack Overflow (and a few other sites) only" to comply with the other sites that also do triage.

Comment: Do you plan to keep SO as the only site with a working Triage help center article? Physics's Triage page still 404s

Comment: @bobble: I'm not sure if we're planning to keep it this way, but... It's worth noting that currently, a help center article can be displayed either only on one site, or on all sites. There's no way for us to include an individual help center article on some sites but not others. (We could manually create an instance of that help center article on each of those sites... but if we did that, we'd need to find and update each other instance of the article every time we made a change to the article - rather than updating it in just one place.)

Comment: See [Slate's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371684/335251) to a related Q&A: [The "product support" page in the Help Center does not make much sense network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238113/335251)