# Privilege page 'Access review queues' still says that Triage is "Stack Overflow only"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, help-center, triage

Similar to [Help Center still says that Triage is "Stack Overflow only"; however, it's enabled on Physics since September](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370706/295232), there is *another* Help Center page that lists the review queues and claims it's Stack Overflow only: the ['access review queues' privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues):

> Learn more about each specific queue and how to perform reviews by visiting these Help center pages:
> ...
>
> - [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow only - 500 reputation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've now updated the list in the ["Access review queues"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege page (`/help/privileges/access-review-queues`) to match the ["What are review queues?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro) help page (`/help/reviews-intro`) – which I recently edited as well – since this issue was already fixed there.

In addition to fixing the issue you point out, I also reorganized the list entries to match the order the review queues appear in on Stack Overflow and other full sites, and added a link back to the ["What are review queues?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro) page.